# Ways to improve this schema/abstraction?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, schema, persistence

I'm making a webapp for an online exam module and was **wondering how my current design and abstraction can be improved.** The exams are multiple choice.

I have three tables in my database so far:

1.exam

- exam_id(primary, auto-inc)
- exam_name - example:"physics", etc
- num_questions
- time_per_question
- points_per_question

2.question

- question_id - primary key, auto_inc
- exam_id - FK referencing exam_id under exam, on update and delete - cascade
- question_text - The actual question itself
- question_figure - name of a file if the question is accompanied by an
  image(ex: graph.jpg). Can be null
- question_category
- question_name - Unique, varchar, something to identify the question by(I plan to use this field so i have a reference to add answer options to, but it feels like its unnecessary)

3.answer

- answer_id - PK, auto_inc
- question_id - Foreign Key referencing question_id under question. cascade on update/delete
- answer_text
- answer_correct - tiny int indicating if its the right answer
- answer_name - Unique, varchar, reference to answer, same as question_name is to question

This is what i have in mind for the classes:

```
public class Exam
{
    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private int timePerQuestionInSeconds;
    private int pointsPerQuestion;
    private int numberOfQuestions;
    private ArrayList<Question> questionList;
}

public class Question
{
    private int Id;
    private int examID;
    private String text;
    private String figure;
    private String category;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Answer> answers;
}

public class Answer
{
    private int id;
    private int questionId;
    private String text;
    private boolean correct;
    private String name;
}
```

So to get an exam i would have to selectbyexamname from exam, then selectbyexamId from question, and then selectbyquestionid from answer. Then take these result sets and map them to objects.

Instead, if i were to use JPA to persist these entities, is it possible to persist an ArrayList of entities? And am i correct in that in class exam

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Question.class, mappedBy="examID")

private ArrayList(Question);

and in class question i should have

@ManyToOne

private examID;

to setup the desired relationship? btw I'm using Java SE so i'm not sure if i have all the support for beans Java EE has.

I'll also need someway to store student's scores of the exams they have taken. I was thinking of having a table score which has fk to student ids and i could query that table by student id to return a student's scores.

Answer (score 0):

Appart from JPA and for every class you write, you should declare your bean variables with interface rather than concrete class if possible. Use java.util.List instead of java.util.ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the num_question attribute in your exam table, is this necessary? Would it not be accurate to count the rows from the Question table?

Also, is the points_per_question dependent on the exam or the question? (I'm thinking its based on question). If so, then it should be an attribute of the Question table, perhaps along with the time_per_question attribute as well. (difficult or longer questions allowing more time?) This is all based on your original requirements.

Otherwise, it looks alright to me.